# Vaadin: How do I add options to a combo box?

Tags: vaadin

I have a combo box that I am trying to add options to. How Do I go about this? This is what I have so far:

```
ComboBox contactPrefixNametf = new ComboBox("Prefix");
contactPrefixNametf.setItemCaption(contactPrefixNametf, "Mr");
fLayout.addComponent(contactPrefixNametf);
contactPrefixNametf.setImmediate(true);
```

I guess `.setItemCaption()` is not the correct method? What is the correct method?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myComboBox.addItem("Option 1");
```

Comment: You'll have strings as your "item identifiers" with this mechanism. It is ok in some simple cases, but most often (with I18n or proper data binding) this is not a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`addItem()`](https://vaadin.com/api/7.5.9/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractSelect.html#addItem%28java.lang.Object%29) method:

```
    final ComboBox my_combox_box = new ComboBox("My Combo Box");
    for (final My_object mo: list_of_my_objects)
    {
        my_combox_box.addItem(mo);
        my_combox_box.setItemCaption(mo, mo.name());
    }
```

This example uses `addItem` inconjunction with [`setItemCaption()`](https://vaadin.com/api/7.5.9/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractSelect.html#setItemCaption%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29) to store the actual object selected by the user with a display friendly name (if [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--) is not appropriate).

Answer (score 0):

(Especially if you are new to Vaadin), I suggest to try [Viritin add-on](https://vaadin.com/addon/viritin) and its TypedSelect variant of ComboBox. Its well typed API makes many things ridiculously simpler. For instance it has a (typed) setOptions method and its value change listeners provide the value directly instead of through untyped Property interface.

A code example of its usage:

```
List<Person> options = service.findMyPersons();

TypedSelect<Person> select = new TypedSelect<>(Person.class)
        .withSelectType(ComboBox.class);
select.setOptions(options);
// If toString() representation is not good, modify it to something else
select.setCaptionGenerator(person -> person.getFirstName() + person.getLastName());

select.addMValueChangeListener(event -> {
    Person person = event.getValue();
});
```

Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of Viritin, but also have maintained Vaadin for 8 years and nowadays work as its developer advocate.